# How to check if a particular pdf in Preview is already open

Tags: bash, macos, grep, xdotool

On Linux I can to something like this:

```
open=`ps -fe | grep "okular ./$main_file_name.pdf" | grep -vc grep`
if [ $open -eq 0 ]
then
    okular ./$main_file_name.pdf &
fi
```

However, on MacOS this does not seem to work. I can only check if Preview is running at all. 
Moreover, I would like to know how to switch to the already opened file. In Linux, I did it with:

```
xdotool search --name $main_file_name.pdf windowactivate
```

Comment: So the question is how to check if a specific filename is opened by Preview? Or do you want to open it again?

Comment: Exactly. I want to check if a filename is opened already in Preview in order to not open it again.

Comment: The macos [`open`](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) command reopens files by itself, could you use that? Something like: `open -a Preview $main_file_name`

Comment: sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately,  `open -a` opens a new instance of the pdf in preview.